# video_capture.read() gives "cv2.error: error: (-215) chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF in function readFrame "

Tags: python, opencv

I want to read my own video of resolution 1080*1920 with OpenCV, but it gives an error.

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/adminroot/zmh/master/camera1.avi')
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

Error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/container_avi.cpp:514: error: (-215) chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF in function readFrame
```

It seems the `read` function has something wrong, or is there some mistake in my code?

Running on my Linux server, opencv-python 3.4.1, Python 3.6.5
The video is a .avi file of 1.6Gb.

Comment: Did you search the many hits for "chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF in function readFrame" here and on the web? Show us what research you h ave done, including ruling out those other Q&A.

Comment: ths for your attention, it said the video is too large to read, there is a limit with the memory of opencv so it cannot read this video, is there some solution to solve this problem?

Comment: i have got a solution in github https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11126,i'll try this, ths!

Comment: Remember that if you find a solution, and it does not seem to be already a duplicate here, you should self-answer for the sweet rep. This is important for future visitors with the same problem, since your comment can be deleted _and_ the link is malformed.